# How do I create components with different directories under same component group?

Tags: wix, wix3.7, heat

How do I create components with different directories under same component group?

Sample Heat command:
"%WIX%bin\heat.exe" dir %SOURCE%\%VERSION% -srd -dr **Video** -cg **Encrypted** -gg -nologo -out abc.wxs -template:fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you manually edit the abc.wxs file you receive as output from the Heat tool, you can move the components to different directories as you wish. You can place several [ComponentRef](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentref.html) elements inside a ComponentGroup to link to the different components you want grouped together:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="MyComponentGroup">
    <ComponentRef Id="Component1"/>
    <ComponentRef Id="Component2"/>
    <ComponentRef Id="Component3"/>
</ComponentGroup>
```

This allows several components to be grouped together, allowing the whole group to be easily references by the similar ComponentGroupRef element.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `heat.exe` is that you can give it a single folder to analyse and generate components (as well as sub-directories containing components) to install. Normally you would have a root install folder. So, let's say your installation directory structure looks like the following:

```
\MyProgramRoot
    \Video <-- The folder you are referencing in the heat.exe command.
    \SomeOtherFolder
    \Etc
```

If this is the case, I would recommend instead running heat on the actual root of your application, that is, `MyProgramRoot`. Your command would like the following based on the prior example:

```
"%WIX%bin\heat.exe" dir %SOURCE%\%VERSION% -srd -dr MyProgramRoot -cg Encrypted -gg -nologo -out abc.wxs -template:fragment
```

What would happen here is, you would still end up with a single component group, **Encrypted**, but `heat.exe` would also generate the various sub-directories, **Video**, SomeOtherFolder, Etc, as well as all of the components with in them.

However, lets say your folder structure is not single root, that is:

```
C:\One\Path\To\Install\Video
C:\Another\Path\To\Install\SomeOtherFolder
C:\Yet\Another\Path\To\Install\Etc
```

This poses a problem as `heat.exe` specializes in WiX code generation for a single root directory. In this scenario, I would invoke `heat.exe` for all of the root directories of my application, and generate component groups for each root directory. Then, you would simply reference those component groups inside the appropriate `Feature` element, like so:

```
<Feature Id="MyMainFeature">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="VideoComponentGroup" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="SomeOtherComponentGroup" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="EtcComponentGroup" />
</Feature>
```

For further information on the capabilities of `Heat.exe` (also known as the Harvest tool), check out the [official documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html).